# 'Non se ne sarebbe accorto nessuno tanto/tanti/quanto/quanti pochi sono i telespettatori per quel programma televisivo'

Tags: grammar

> a) Non se ne sarebbe accorto nessuno **tanti pochi sono** i telespettatori per quel programma televisivo.
>
> b) Non se ne sarebbe accorto nessuno **tanto pochi sono** i telespettatori per quel programma televisivo.
>
> c) Non se ne sarebbe accorto nessuno **quanti sono pochi** [o 'pochi sono'] i telespettatori per quel programma televisivo.
>
> d) Non se ne sarebbe accorto nessuno **quanto sono pochi** [o 'pochi sono'] i telespettatori per quel programma televisivo.

Quale dovremmo preferire e perché?

Comment: La b (*tanto* avverbio): *tanto pochi sono gli spettatori che nessuno se ne sarebbe accorto*.

Comment: I would say "tanto sono pochi" or "da quanto pochi sono", actually

Answer (score 2):

La risposta più adatta è la **B**. In alternativa potresti girare la frase dicendo:
*"I telespettatori sono così pochi che non se ne sarebbe accorto nessuno"*
o
*"Così pochi sono i telespettatori, che non se ne sarebbe accorto nessuno"*

Answer (score 1):

Come dice AltGei la risposta corretta tra quelle proposte è sicuramente la **B**:

> b) Non se ne sarebbe accorto nessuno **tanto pochi sono** i telespettatori per quel programma televisivo.

Però, come suggerisce mau, quello che molti direbbero nella vita di tutti i giorni è **B2**:

> b2) Non se ne sarebbe accorto nessuno **tanto sono pochi** i telespettatori per quel programma televisivo.

La versione B ("tanto pochi sono") suona eccessivamente formale e pomposa.

Answer (score 0):

Quanto sono pochi è corretto.

---

Motivo: Quando c'è il verbo essere e un'aggettivo (anche al plurale) si usa **Quanto**.

Comment: Non capisco questa risposta.

Answer (score -1):

La **B**.

In realtà in questa frase *"tanto"* è usato con valore conclusivo e non di quantità.

Allo stesso modo, potresti rimpiazzarlo per ***"dopotutto"*** oppure ***"in ogni modo"***.

Per cui, potremmo riformulare la B:

*Non se ne sarebbe accorto nessuno dopotutto sono pochi i telespettatori per quel programma televisivo.*

Comment: Oh my God, davvero?

Comment: Se hai dei dubbi posso chiarire.

Comment: Non direi proprio...

Comment: La risposta è corretta, ma i sinonimi che hai proposto non c'entrano assolutamente nulla.

Comment: @pinckerman Non sono sinonimi... sono avverbi.

Comment: Fino a prova contraria anche gli avverbi hanno dei sinonimi.

Comment: No, io direi che la frase è una consecutiva, non una conclusiva (esiste la conclusiva in italiano?)